# Inner datagrid is firing the selection change event of the outer data grid C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a inner datagrid using row details template:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="OuterGrid" SelectionChanged="OuterGrid_SelectionChanged">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name ="Header" Header="Header"     IsReadOnly="True" Width="480">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Expander x:Name="Expander" Grid.Row="0"     Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed">
            <Expander.Header>
              <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockExp" Margin="15,0,0,0" Text="{Binding HeaderLabel}"/>
            </Expander.Header>
            <Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Expander>
          <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource=    {RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="TextBlockExp" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <DataGrid x:Name="InnerGrid"  SelectionChanged="InnerGrid_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding InnerGridList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSecondItem}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding AValue}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="320">
          </DataGridTextColumn>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding BValue}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="250">
          </DataGridTextColumn>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="C" Binding="{Binding CValue}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="250">
          </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Binding of the outer grid and inner grid are already OK. However, when i try to change the selected item in inner grid, the selection change event of the outer grid is also called.

```
private void OuterGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (OuterGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
   {
                OuterGridModel row =     (OuterGridModel)OuterGrid.SelectedItems[0];
                PopulateInnerGrid(row.InnerGridList);
                row.SelectedSecondItem = row.InnerGridList[0];
   }
}
```

When I set the selected item using this line (as shown above):

```
row.SelectedSecondItem = row.InnerGridList[0];
```

`InnerGrid_SelectionChanged` is fired, also `OuterGrid_SelectionChanged` is fired.
I only want `InnerGrid_SelectionChanged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectionChanged` is a [routedevent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview) and it's bubbling up in the element tree, both the inner and outer `DataGrid` listen to it.
An easy fix to your issue is to set the `Handled` property of the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` to true, so that the event won't be handled any further.

```
 private void InnerGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
          //...
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: You are welcome, please accept the answer if this is what you were looking for.